# How to display according to Generation, x 'Attack' and y 'Defense'

Tags: python

I am a beginner. I can't display graphs by color grouping by Generation.
Generation has a total of 6.

If you see picture the result of the code is now that the graph is displayed in one color

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv("../input/pokemon/Pokemon.csv")
x = df['Attack']
y = df['Defense']
z = df['Generation']

tableau20 = [(31, 119, 180), (174, 199, 232), (255, 127, 14), (255, 187, 120),  
             (44, 160, 44), (152, 223, 138), (214, 39, 40), (255, 152, 150),  
             (148, 103, 189), (197, 176, 213), (140, 86, 75), (196, 156, 148),  
             (227, 119, 194), (247, 182, 210), (127, 127, 127), (199, 199, 199),  
             (188, 189, 34), (219, 219, 141), (23, 190, 207), (158, 218, 229)]



for i in range(len(tableau20)):  
    r, g, b = tableau20[i]  
    tableau20[i] = (r / 255., g / 255., b / 255.)

colors = tableau20[::2]
f, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in np.unique(z):

    plt.scatter(x , y  , label=i , color=colors[i])

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

I expect display graphs by color grouping by generation:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atKSa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

For every i in your code, you are plotting the entire dataset, because you define `x,y` at the start of your code. A quick fix would be to define `x,y` on the subset of the data that matches the generation:

```
for i in np.unique(z):

    #define x,y on the part of the df that matches the resp. Generation
    df2 = df[df['Generation']==i]       
    x = df2['Attack']
    y = df2['Defense']

    plt.scatter(x , y  , label=i , color=colors[i])
```

But if the values in `df['Generation']` are int, you can also simply do:

```
cols = [colors[a] for a in df['Generation']]      
plt.scatter(df['Attack'], df['Defense'], c=cols)
```

Comment: if this answers the question, please consider accepting it